# Extend boot partition in lvm on Centos 7

Tags: centos7, parted

I have a CentOS 7 with a Boot Partition  of 400M as number 1. And after that I have a root Partition of 50G as number 2. What would be the steps to extend the Boot volume with parted or so ?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Using any backup utility you'd like, You would need to backup your root partition to another drive. Then you can reinstall CentOS with a larger boot partition.

Before you do all that, You should attempt to clean up your boot partition and remove the extra files.

**CentOS 7** `package-cleanup -y --oldkernels --count=1 && package-cleanup -y --cleandupes`

***CentOS 8+*** `dnf remove --duplicates`